# How to use Google Calendar's "Private Address" with gdata.calendar.service?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, gdata

There are several examples online describing how to use the gdata.calendar.service (I mistakenly wrote "client" here) class to log in to a calendar with an email address and a password. Is there a way to use the calendar's "Private Address" (be it xml or ical) in gdata.calendar.service? I don't want to hard code my password in a script if I can avoid it.

The "Private Address" is a URL that looks something like:

https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/${somestring}%40group.calendar.google.com/private-${someotherstring}/basic

and you can get it from a link at the bottom of the "calendar settings" page.

I am the latest version of gdata for python: gdata-2.0.16.

Answer (score 0):

This should work pretty much straightforward. IIRC you need to set visibility to "private-YOURTOKEN", instead of "public". Then it will build the proper URL.

However, you must be aware that the access via this private URL is **readonly**. For write access, you need to do the full password authentication.